# Why sometimes the javascript menu toggle turns into a link instead of toggling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Issue:** I have a sidebar that toggles when clicked (goes away to left) but sometimes i notice, for instance when i click a link and go back in browser - and then click the toggle button, it will do this instead of toggling:

```
http://localhost:3000/dashboard#menu-toggle
```

And then not toggle.  If i reload the page, it still won't work.  I will need to leave the dashboard, go to homepage, and back to dashboard, for it to work.

It doesn't happen a lot, but it will randomly happen when I'm going through the dashboard layout.

This is the javascript:

```
<script>

          $(function(){
           $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
           });

           $(window).resize(function(e) {
             if($(window).width()<=768){
               $("#wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
             }else{
               $("#wrapper").addClass("toggled");
             }
           });
         });

</script>
```

What could possibly be creating this issue?

I took this sidebar template and created my own from it, but i haven't changed much: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/7np2j

The only changes i have made so far is the color and fixing the navbar to the top, but these wouldn't cause this issue.

Other than that issue, it works fine.

Are there any edits that should be made to that javascript so this doesn't happen?

UPDATE:
After responses saying its because the page isn't loaded i did some testing.

The issue still happens even if the page is Completed.

Anyone have a better toggle code than what I current am using?

**UPDATE 2:**

I noticed the issue was always stemming from one page.  The one thing this page had that none other did was:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

For a bootstrap 4 tooltip hover.

Removing this from the page and completely from the layout worked. The issue will persist when it's present.

What's the issue with this?

Comment: It's possible that the script listening for the click hasn't loaded yet. A lot of button and menu code tend to just be an anchor tag `<a>` with some fancy styling on it. For example your `menu-toggle` button is just `<a href="#menu-toggle"></>` with a hamburger menu icon. Note that the `href` points to `#menu-toggle`. If the script is loaded and listening properly, it will intercept the click and activate the menu. If the script hasn't loaded, the browser translates the click to the default behavior of following the link in the `href` property of the `<a>` tag.

Comment: First off, you need to make sure jquery is loaded successfully. What you described suggests it did not

Comment: Hmmm I see.  Is there any way around it or better practices? would it be better to have a button to open the toggle, and then a separate one to close it - is that a better practice? - instead of one button to toggle both ways?

Comment: Now whats the issue with it not working when reloaded? Say i click, /dashboard on the sidebar, it doesn't work, i click it again after removing the #menu-toggle from the URL, it won't work.  I need to leave the dashboard layout alltogether.  Why does it break and stay broken even on reload?

Comment: btw, i ended up figuring it out,  updated in OP